# On kubernetes helm how to replace a pod with new config values

Tags: docker, kubernetes, config, kubernetes-helm

I am using helm charts to deploy pods with a "ConfigMap" managing the configurations.

I edit ConfigMap directly to make changes to configuration files and then delete pods using kubectl delete, for the new configuration to take effect.

Is there any easy way using **helm** to replace a running pod with the new configuration without executing "**kubectl delete**" command

Answer (score 26):

We have found that using `--recreate-pods` will immediately terminate all running pods of that deployment, meaning some downtime for your service. In other words, there will be no rolling update of your pods.

The issue to address this in Helm is still open: https://github.com/kubernetes/helm/issues/1702

Instead helm suggests adding a checksum of your configuration files to the deployment in an annotation. That way the deployment will have a different hash and essentially look 'new' to helm, causing it to update correctly.

> The sha256sum function can be used to ensure a deployment's annotation section is updated if another file changes:

```
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        checksum/config: {{ include (print $.Template.BasePath "/configmap.yaml") . | sha256sum }}
[...]
```

From the docs here: https://helm.sh/docs/charts_tips_and_tricks/#automatically-roll-deployments-when-configmaps-or-secrets-change

Comment: Does this work for Helm charts stored in repositories? I think this breaks the purpose of repositories, all charts would have to be pulled locally.

Comment: Hmm, not sure what you mean. If this snippet of code is in a helm chart, and that chart is in a repository, then it should work just fine.

Comment: This would work for a code repository, like Git. But would it work for a Helm artifacts repository, such as S3, in which files are kept in a mychart-0.1.0.tgz format?

Comment: As far as I know theres no difference there. Tiller runs the chart through its templating and out comes the same thing. Unless my mental model is wrong somewhere, there is no difference between a chart stored in git or one stored somewhere else.

Comment: It didn't work here. I could see the new annotation metadata by describing the deployment but pods were not recreated.

Answer (score 4):

If you need a rolling update instead of immediatly terminating pods, add

```
date: "{{ .Release.Time.Seconds }}"
```

into the spec/template/metadata/labels.

The release will then have a config change, which triggers a rolling update if set as spec/stategy/type.

In case you just changed a ConfigMap or Secret, have a look at https://helm.sh/docs/developing_charts/#automatically-roll-deployments-when-configmaps-or-secrets-change

Answer (score 2):

You can run

> helm upgrade --recreate-pods

to do this.

Comment: I would not recommend this approach if you need zero downtime deploys. The `--recreate-pods` flag immediately terminates all running pods of the deployment.

Answer (score 0):

@Oliver solution didn't work for me because pods were not recreated by updating the deployment annotations.

The solution is to use dynamic config map names based on your values.yaml file.

In values.yaml:

```
configVersion: # Change those numbers to force recreating pods
  myApp: 1
```

In your config map:

```
metadata:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-my-config-v{{ .Values.configVersion.myApp}}
```

In your deployment:

```
- configMapRef:
  name: {{ .Release.Name }}-my-config-v{{ .Values.configVersion.myApp}}
```

Comment: Possibly you made the same mistake as me, I accidentally put the annotation on the deployment (spec.metadata.annotations) and the pods weren't restarted.  They tell you to put the annotations on the template (spec.template.metadata.annotations) and it worked when I moved the annotation there.