# How do I upgrade a helm chart with a new values.yaml and keep the previous deployments data?

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm

I deployed a helm chart using `config-v1.yaml`. I added some data to my helm chart app via an api exposed in the helm chart

I want to deploy/update the current chart with values from `config-v2.yaml` because there is a feature I want to expose.

When I use `helm upgrade -f config-v2.yaml my-chart stable/chart`. The previous helm version is blown away meaning the data I added with the API is gone. So I figure I need to add a volume to my container.

When I add a PersistentVolume and PersistentVolumeClaim, the app fails to update with values from `config-v2.yaml` which means I don't get the new features I want.

What is the proper way to do these types of updates to helm charts?

Comment: I'm not quite sure how helm differs exactly, but I do know that in raw k8s, you'd need to allocate a persistent volume, and your config would need to procure a persistent volume claim to be able to save state between runs.  All other data is ephemeral.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how it fails to update with the values you want following the upgrade? You should be able to update and keep data in a volume. I wonder if you're hitting something like https://rancher.com/blog/2018/2018-07-10-helm-tips-and-tricks-updating-app-with-configmap/

Comment: Its not a failure per say, I get the success message I want. However when I go to the chart, the changes from the new configuration file is not reflected. How come adding a volume doesn't help the situation. I basically want it to work similar to docker compose. When I destroy my containers and restart them, they read from the existing volumes, and start up reflecting the new changes. 

BTW: awesome article! Not related but I'll be using that trick soon.

Comment: I guess I should ask what changes specifically and which resource do they apply to (e.g. configmap, pod)? If you add --recereate-pods to the helm upgrade (like in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44268277/on-kubernetes-helm-how-to-replace-a-pod-with-new-config-values) does it then reflect the changes?

Comment: so where are you keeping your state? database? pod disk/mount? what are the components of your helm chart? frontend? db? broker?

Comment: Could you provide more details about how do you add that PV and PVC to your chart. YAML example would be helpful.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

To upgrade, use '--reuse-values' flag as you are providing extra customization to the existing values.

In your case, you can use

helm upgrade **--reuse-values** -f config-v2.yaml my-chart stable/chart

Please refer the [docs.](https://helm.sh/docs/helm/helm_upgrade/)

Comment: IME, ` --reuse-values` does not stop `-f config-v2.yaml` from blowing away previous values specified in `config-v2.yaml`. So it seems that a `config-v2.yaml` isn't compatible with Helm's workflow in the first place. Instead, you need to specify only differences from previous versions in your `values.yaml`, leaving it up to Helm users to keep up with what has and has not been applied to each release, correct?

Comment: @jtlz2 Fixed the doc link. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Use the '--version' flag to set your version.  Look up current version first via 'helm list -A' and set it.  This issue caught me as well.